# 15.10 hangs on loading on Lenovo thinkpad tablet 2

Tags: live-usb, lenovo, tablet

I followed [this instruction](https://sturmflut.github.io/linux/ubuntu/2015/02/04/installing-ubuntu-on-baytrail-tablets-version-2/)

Got access to grub boot menu: Try ubuntu..., Install ubuntu..., OEM install..., Check disk...

Selecting any item of menu leads to blank scren, couple of seconds blinking by USB then hangs.

I've tried 14.10 amd64, 15.10 amd64 with same results.
Tried 14.10 x86, 15.10 x86 - these simply throw me to grub command line.

Really appreciate any help on how can I diagnose the root cause of hanging ?
Or probably any workarounds ?

Answer (score 0):

This is missing functionaltiy in grub2 / ubuntu  for UEFI 32-bit BIOS

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1341944

It might be a good idea to  copy  latest debian EFI loader to Ubuntu 15.10 64-bit boot , as the the last comment in the bug report suggests, and not the EFI loader which is mentioned in the instruction , as it refers to older 14.10 ubuntu installation .

Update -  the Atom processor  in this tablet does not support 64-bit instructions, so we must use 32-bit Ubuntu installer, which in turn not support UEFI at all.
So better to try multi-arch Debian instead, according to Intel blogs.

http://blogs.intel.com/evangelists/2015/08/11/update-on-ia32-uefi-and-linux-support/

Comment: Suggestion: Since the comment in bug report only mentioned "copy the right EFI loader from Debian", this answer could specify where to find the EFI loader from Debian by providing filename or source directory where it can be found. While the current answer might be correct, it is not helpful (users still need to search where is "that right EFI loader from Debian").

Comment: suggested link to multi-arch debian boot image http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current/multi-arch/iso-cd/debian-8.2.0-amd64-i386-netinst.iso